# How to round off milliseconds value from timestamp(0) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, rounding

I need to round off milliseconds value from `timestamp(0) without time zone`.

Ex: 2018-04-19 10:43:13.**719** to 2018-04-19 10:43:13.**000**

Comment: Do you mean to *round* or *truncate* like your example indicates? Also, `timestamp(0)` does not store milliseconds to begin with. That's what the appended `(0)` is for. Do you maybe have a different source type, and only the target is `timestamp(0)` and want to truncate instead of round in the assignment? Or is it a display issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

`SELECT date_trunc('seconds', '2018-04-19 10:43:13.719'::timestamp);`

Comment: this will display 2018-04-19 10:43:13 only milliseconds discarded. millisecond value should be round off.

Comment: The milliseconds are only shown if they are set. If you really want to display `.000` at the end, you can do `truncated_ts::text || '.000'`.

Answer (score 2):

None of this is applicable to `timestamp(0)` like you suggested, since that type does not store milliseconds to begin with. Would make sense for literal input or `timestamp` (without precision modifier).

***Rounding*** the timestamp `'2018-04-19 10:43:13.719'` would give you `'2018-04-19 10:43:14'` (rounded *up*).

To ***truncate*** microseconds, you can use [date_trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), like Lorenz already provided. According to your comment you still want the redundant dangling '.000'. For display I suggest [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('seconds', timestamp '2018-04-19 10:43:13.719'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

Or cheaper, append '.000' instead of actual milliseconds with `to_char()` directly:

```
SELECT to_char(timestamp '2018-04-19 10:43:13.719', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS".000"')
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE)

> Ordinary text is allowed in `to_char` templates and will be output
>   literally. You can put a substring in double quotes to force it to be
>   interpreted as literal text even if it contains template patterns.