# How to insert time without fractional seconds?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

When I insert the time in my table with the `current_time` function I get this: `16:42:41.095644`.

But I want this: `16:42:41` or this: `16:42`.

Is there any way to this? It might not even be with `current_time`, I can use any other function, but how do I do I insert time like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **never** use `CURRENT_TIME`. It returns the type `time with time zone`, the use of which is [discouraged in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) because it's an inherently broken construct. The type (and the function `CURRENT_TIME`)  are only supported because standard SQL sadly defined them this way. See:

- [Comparing TIME WITH TIME ZONE returns unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124222/comparing-time-with-time-zone-returns-unexpected-result/63126204#63126204)
- [Postgres time with time zone equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529284/postgres-time-with-time-zone-equality/20530283#20530283)

`LCOALTIME` (returning `timestamp`) makes more sense. But you can just use `now()` (= `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) for *everything*. Local time always depends on the current time zone setting of the session anyway. See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Of course, you can cast `timestamp` or `timstamptz` to `time`:

To **round** to full seconds:

```
INSERT INTO my_tbl(my_time_col)
VALUES (LOCALTIME::time(0)::time);
```

To **truncate** to seconds or minutes, ...

```
date_trunc('second', LOCALTIMESTAMP)::time
date_trunc('minute', LOCALTIMESTAMP)::time
```

This is equivalent:

```
date_trunc('second', LOCALTIME)::time
date_trunc('minute', LOCALTIME)::time
```

The expression `date_trunc('second', LOCALTIME)` returns `interval`, so the cast to `time` may or may not be needed. In an `INSERT` writing to a `time` column, the type is coerced automatically.

`date_trunc('second', LOCALTIMESTAMP)` returns `timestamp`. The explicit cast to `time` may still be optional for the same reason.

Related:

- [How to round off milliseconds value from timestamp(0) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002714/how-to-round-off-milliseconds-value-from-timestamp0-in-postgresql/55010430#55010430)

Answer (score 1):

`time` is stored using an internal format.

But you can convert a `timestamp` to a string, but not a `time` to a string directly.  So one workaround is to add a date component:

```
select to_char('2000-01-01'::date + current_time, 'HH24:MI')
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . The data type in the question is `time`, not `timestamp`.  I clarified the language, though, because it was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

`current_date` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Note: Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the "current" time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.