# SELECT date and time without second-fractions from unix epoch

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002714/how-to-round-off-milliseconds-value-from-timestamp0-in-postgresql/55010430#55010430)  isn't exactly what I wanted.

I have for example:

```sql
select to_timestamp(1476544839);
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2016-10-15 16:20:39+01
(1 row)
```

But I do not want the fractional part of seconds.

Expected:

```sql
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2016-10-15 16:20:39
```

PGSQL version:

```sql
 select version();
                                                               version                                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.20 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.20-1.pgdg18.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

**EDIT**

As a follow up to the question, I have this column named `timestamp` created with time zone.

```sql
> \d my_table;
                   View "postgres.my_table"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 session_id | integer                  |           |          | 
 timestamp  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 seconds    | integer                  |           |          | 
...            ...
```

And so

```sql
SELECT timestamp FROM my_table
         timestamp          
----------------------------
 2016-03-17 08:33:51.842+00
 2016-03-17 08:33:51.738+00
 2016-03-17 08:33:50.794+00
(3 rows)
```

It is these fractional part of seconds `.842 .739 .794` that I do not want.

Comment: in my pgsql i get `2016-10-15 18:20:39`

Comment: strange, using psql too.

Comment: +01 mean your time zone

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1476544839)::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC'`
try this

Comment: Exactly, that's it.

Comment: @Nickname_used I made an edit to my question.

Comment: `SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1476544839), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` this doesnt work too ?

Comment: Declare the column as `timestamptz(0)`  then it doesn't store fractional seconds

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1476544839)::timestamp(0); 10/15/2016 08:20:39` or `select to_timestamp(1476544839)::timestamptz(0); 10/15/2016 08:20:39 PDT
`.